# Can't access the memory which was malloc() in DLL

Tags: dll, dynamic-memory-allocation

Dear,

Recently I run into a general issue, I am writing a DLL, which will be used/invoked by another program. It has structure like this :

```
DLLEXT long AMI_Init(void **AMI_dll_memory)
{
    mem = (struct model_memory*)malloc(sizeof(struct model_memory));
    mem->submem = (struct submem*)malloc(sizeof(struct submem));
    ......
    *AMI_dll_memory = (void*)mem;
}

DLLEXT long AMI_Get(void *AMI_dll_memory)
{
    ....
    mem = (struct model_memory*)AMI_dll_memory;
    mem->submem->init(); 
} 

// Defined in submem module
struct {
    int data;
    struct list* next;
}list;

void init()
{
    struct list* n;
    n = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    // access n->data caused memory access violation.
}
```

Another software will invoke the AMI_Init() first, then call AMI_Get() with passing the AMI_dll_memory in between, but I got access violation once I tried to access the data "n->data" of "mem->submem->init()". Why it is ? I confirmed I can apply memory since the malloc funtion returned successfully, but just can't access n->data, anyone know why it is ? n->data didn't belong to current process after memory passing in funtions ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys,

I figure out what is going on here, it is related to implicit declaration of malloc() function, when I malloc memory in second places, I didn't include stdlib.h in that file, which caused the issue.